# How to search and print a line from txt file in python3?

Tags: python, python-3.x, txt

So I'm learning python3 at the moment through university - entirely new to it *(not really a strong point of mine haha)*, and i'm not quite sure what i'm missing - even after going through my course content

So the program in question is a text based Stock Management program
and part of the brief is that i be able to search for a line in the text file and print the line on the program

```
def lookupstock():
StockFile = open('file.txt', 'r')
flag = 0
index = 0
search = str(input("Please enter in the Item: "))

for line in StockFile:
    index += 1

    if search in line:
        flag = 1
        break

if flag == 0:
    print(search, "Not Found")
else:
    print(search)
    StockFile.close()
```

However the output is only what i have typed in if it exists rather than the whole line itself so lets say the line i want to print is 'Kit-Kat, 2003, 24.95' and i search for Kit-Kat

Since the line exists - the output is only

```
Kit-Kat
```

Rather than the whole line
Where have I gone wrong? Was I far off?

Greatly appreciated, thank you!

Comment: you should print `line` not `search` which is the word you search

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Something like this

```
if flag == 0:
    print(search, "Not Found")
else:
    print(search, 'find in line N° ', index , ' line:',line )
    StockFile.close()
```

Answer (score 0):

Alternatively you could open your file using a context manager. This will automatically handle closing the file, here's an example:

```
def lookupstock():
    flag = False
    with open('file.txt', 'r') as StockFile:
        search = str(input("Please enter in the Item: "))
        for index, line in enumerate(StockFile):
            if search in line:
                print(line, f"Found at line {index}")
                flag = True
    if not flag:
        print(search, "Not Found")

lookupstock()
```

Results:

```
Please enter in the Item: test
test Not Found
Please enter in the Item: hello
hello Found at line 0
```

Answer (score 0):

Setting flags, breaking the loop then testing the flag is not good practice - it's unnecessarily complex. Try this instead:

```
def LookupStock():
    search = input('Enter search item: ')
    with open('file.txt') as StockFile:
        for line in StockFile:
            if search in line:
                print(line)
                break
        else:
            print(search, ' not found')
```